# Display loading progress on Blazor .net 8 WebAssembly pre-render false?

Tags: .net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

Using .net 8 RC2.

I'm creating a page that runs only on WebAssembly and I need to have pre-rendering **disabled** (by using `@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveWebAssembly(prerender: false)]`).

Is there a way to display the loading spinner (as we had on .net 7) when the user navigates to this page? (during js .net load time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do it using the following code.

In App.razor add a script to app.js as well as a reference to a loading element:

```html
...
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender: false)" />
</head>

<body>
    <b id="loading">Loading</b>
    <Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender: false)"></Routes>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

Then create a javascript file called app.js:

```js
(function () {

    window.deleteElementById = function (id) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }

})();
```

Then finally in Routes.razor use the following code to call the javascript via interop:

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime;

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>

@code{
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("deleteElementById", "loading");
        }
    }
}
```